# Strange error when PhpStorm's xdebug listener is enabled

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Only one page has this error

> is_readable(): Unable to find the wrapper "xdebug" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Other pages work correctly with xdebug enabled and the listener turned on in PhpStorm.

If the xdebug listener is disabled in PhpStorm, the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it must be an issue with your code (your own or some 3rd party library that you may use). When you debugging (debug connection is established) xdebug generates a file name `xdebug://xdebug-eval` -- you may have a routine in your code where such file name is somehow passed to `is_readable()`. For example, PHPUnit could get into such situation a year ago or so.

Comment: I catched this error when my debug session was died by timeout. After this a begin to get this error. On other mac with this code revision this problem can not reply.

Comment: No other ideas, sorry.

Comment: In xDebug console i was found reasons of this behaviour. xDebug cant to evaluate some expressions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

**Check your IDE watch expressions**. I had watch on "$ex->getMessage()" that was causing a method call on null object and it broke execution only when xdebug was used. Very annoying, very hard to catch.